# Is the code below converting a character into its ASCII value?

Tags: c++, c

Is the code below converting a character into its ASCII value?.
I faced a piece of code while studying evaluation of postfix operation,where it says "the expression converts a single digit character in C to its numerical value".?

```
int x=getch();  
int c=x-'0';      /*does c have the ASCII value of x?*/
printf("%d",c);
```

Comment: "Numerical value of **digit**" != ASCII value.

Comment: You are doing a subtraction of x - value of the character 0....If you ran this code you would have seen this.

Comment: Try inputting these characters: '$' and 'A'.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's converting the ASCII value to a number >= 0.

Let's say you type '1'.  `getch()` will return 49 which is the ASCII value of '1'.  49 - '0' is the same as 49 - 48 (48 being the ASCII value for '0').  Which gives you 1.

Note that this code is broken if you enter a character that is not a number.
E.g. if you type 'r' it will print `'r' - '0'` = `114 - 48` = `66`

([Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).)

Comment: Sorry, it is not converting an ASCII value to a number >= 0.  Try using 0x24, '$', as the value in x.  According to ASCII, the $ has value 0x24 and `0` has value of 0x30.  The result of the subtraction is negative.

Comment: Well, it's goal is to do that.  As I pointed out the code is broken.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's giving the numeric value of a digit.  So '5' (53 in ASCII) becomes 5.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  
So the getch() returns the ascii value of the character which is then stored in **x**,and by subtracting **'0'** i get the character's numerical value..please correct me if i am wrong!..?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the code below converting a character into its ASCII value?

It isn't. It's doing the opposite (converting an ASCII value to the numerical value) and it only works for decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

To print the ascii value all you need to do is :

```
int x=getch();  
printf("%d",x);
```

If you are sure that you only want to accept integers as input then you need to put some constraints to the input before proceeding to process them.

```
int x = getch();
if (x >='0' || x <= '9') {
    int c = x - '0'; // c will have the value of the digit in the range 0-9 
    . . .     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any character(in your case numbers) enclosed within single quotes is compiled to its ASCII value. The following line in the snippet above translates to,

int c=x-'0';  ---> int c= x-48; //48 is the ASCII value of '0'

When the user inputs any character to your program, it gets translated to integer as follow,

If x = '1', ASCII of '1' = 49, so c= 49-48 = 1

If x = '9', ASCII of '9' = 57, so c= 57-48 = 9 and so on.